# React hook form two inputs with same register key

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

Have simple form with two almost identical inputs. One with range slider, another with input type number. Components from MUI library.

```
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";
import MuiInput from "@mui/material/Input";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
//...

const { handleSubmit, register, control, } = useForm<{
    level: number;
}>({
    defaultValues: {
        level: 1,
    },
});

const [numberInput, setNumberInput] = useState<number>(5);

const handleNumberInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setNumberInput(e.target.valueAsNumber);
};

const handleSliderChange = (event: Event, value: number | number[], activeThumb: number) => {
    setNumberInput(value as number);
};


<Slider
    {...register("level")}
    valueLabelDisplay="auto"
    step={1}
    min={1}
    max={20}
    marks={gameComplexityLevels}
    value={numberInput}
    onChange={handleSliderChange}
/>
<MuiInput
    size="small"
    {...register("level")}
    onChange={handleNumberInputChange}
    inputProps={{
        step: 1,
        min: 0,
        value: numberInput,
        max: 20,
        type: "number",
        "aria-labelledby": "input-slider",
    }}
/>
```

User can change same value from `Slider` either `MuiInput` component. The problem is that react-hook-form does not allow keys with same name.

```
{...register("level")}
```

This line is duplicating.
Also, the inputs does not work correctly. When I remove `register` line, everything works as expected. But with register line components work unstable. Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Would you please try this, you can set the value using `setValue` `react-hook-form` prop, you can see the docs from [this link](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/setvalue), and you can get the `level` value from `getValue` like `getValue('level')`

```
import Slider from "@mui/material/Slider";
import MuiInput from "@mui/material/Input";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
//...

const { handleSubmit, register, control, setValue} = useForm<{
    level: number;
}>({
    defaultValues: {
        level: 1,
    },
});

const [numberInput, setNumberInput] = useState<number>(5);

const handleNumberInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    setNumberInput(e.target.valueAsNumber);
    setValue("level", e.target.valueAsNumber);
};

const handleSliderChange = (event: Event, value: number | number[], activeThumb: number) => {
    setNumberInput(value as number);
    setValue("level", value as number);
};


<Slider
    valueLabelDisplay="auto"
    step={1}
    min={1}
    max={20}
    marks={gameComplexityLevels}
    value={numberInput}
    onChange={handleSliderChange}
/>
<MuiInput
    size="small"
    onChange={handleNumberInputChange}
    inputProps={{
        step: 1,
        min: 0,
        value: numberInput,
        max: 20,
        type: "number",
        "aria-labelledby": "input-slider",
    }}
/>
```